# How do I connect an external monitor using a VGA cable to a laptop running Fedora?

Tags: multiple-monitors, fedora-15

I have a Sony Vaio laptop which has two operating systems, Windows and Fedora 15 (32 bit). I want to connect an external LCD monitor to my laptop using a VGA cable. The external monitor is working on Windows, but its not working on Fedora.

I tried the command `disper -S` but it shows:

> "No secondary display found, falling back to primary display"

Please help me, step by step, to resolve my problem.

Comment: Have you looked at [these](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=283241) [forum](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=268526) pages?

Comment: What video card?

Comment: Fedora 15 is quite old. You may have better luck with a newer release, which will have better hardware support.